# Is it okay to ask my manager/team lead of my IT firm that I can’t work under constant monitoring?

Tags: india, workplace-rhythm

I have been working on a startup company in India for a year now. There are some people in my company who like to keep a constant watch on my work. Like asking me the status report every hour, or every 30 minutes. Sometimes, I am being kept watched by some tracking software or camera. I know this is very common, but my output really degrades and my efficiency lowers when I work under constant monitoring.

Should I take this issue up with my manager?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/128133/discussion-on-question-by-asish-is-it-okay-to-ask-my-manager-team-lead-of-my-it).

Answer (score 20, accepted):

If this is normal in your company, then asking for it to be changed, just for you, is potentially career limiting. It's unlikely to be changed, you will just attract negative attention.

Generally, if you are unhappy with a company's culture or procedures, then it's better to leave than rock the boat. Both for the sake of your reputation and your revenue stream.

Comment: How would they know it will not be the same at a different company? Perhaps address that in your answer (e.g., proposals for how to find out)?

Comment: @PeterMortensen: It's unnatural. The majority of companies don't camera monitor all the time.

Comment: @Joshua The majority of software companies in California/the US or the majority of companies in OP's industry in whatever part of India they're living?

Comment: @NotThatGuy: I have reason to believe in India it's the same; most companies do not do that kind of surveillance. You will also find this claim in the question comments.

Comment: @Joshua Some companies monitor their employees quite closely. Some of those companies are even in the US. If your "reason to believe in India it's the same" is "it doesn't happen in any of the company's I've worked for or know of in the US", that's not a particularly convincing case. OP is literally at such a company right now. That's not a big enough sample size to generalise with, but it should make you think twice about generalising in the opposite direction.